# kinesis stream account incorrect

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I have setup my pc with python and connections to AWS.  This has been successfully tested using the s3_sample.py file, I had to create an IAM user account with the credentials in a file which worked fine for S3 buckets.

My next task was to create an mqtt bridge and put some data in a stream in kinesis using the awslab - [awslabs/mqtt-kinesis-bridge](https://github.com/awslabs/mqtt-kinesis-bridge).
This seems to be all ok except I get an error when I run the bridge.py.  The error is:

```
Could not find ACTIVE stream:my_first_stream error:Stream my_first_stream under account 673480824415 not found.
```

Strangely this is not the account I use in the .boto file that is suggested to be set up for this bridge, which are the same credentials I used for the S3 bucket

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = AA1122BB
aws_secret_access_key = LlcKb61LTglis
```

It would seem to me that the bridge.py has a hardcoded account but I can not see it and i can't see where it is pointing to the .boto file for credentials.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is a simple Github repo, the python use boto modules, which defaultly use the config file under ~/.boto. If you need take deep investigation, you need check in [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto)

Answer (score 1):

So the issue of not finding the Active stream for the account is resolved by:

1. ensure you are hooked into the US-EAST-1 data centre as this is the default data centre for bridge.py
2. create your stream, you will only need 1 shard

The next problem stems from the specific version of MQTT and the python library paho-mqtt I installed. The bridge application was written with the API of MQTT 1.2.1 using paho-mqtt 0.4.91 in mind. 
The new version which is available for download on their website has a different way of interacting with the paho-mqtt library which passes an additional "flags" object to the on_connect callback. This generates the error I was experiencing, since its not expecting the 5th argument.

You should be able to fix it by making the following change to bridge.py
Line 104 currently looks like this: 
    def on_connect(self, mqttc, userdata, msg):
Simply add flags, after userdata, so that the callback function looks like this:
    def on_connect(self, mqttc, userdata,flags, msg):

This should resolve the issue of the final error of the incorrect number of arguments being passed.

Hope this helps others, thank for the efforts.

Answer (score 0):

When you call python SDK for aws service, there is a line to import the boto modules for aws services in `bridge.py`.

```
import boto
```

The setting is pointing to the .boto for credentials and defined defaultly in boto.

Here is the explanation [Boto Config](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html) :

#### Details

A boto config file is a text file formatted like an .ini configuration file that specifies values for options that control the behavior of the boto library. In Unix/Linux systems, on startup, the boto library looks for configuration files in the following locations and in the following order:

```
/etc/boto.cfg - for site-wide settings that all users on this machine will use
~/.boto - for user-specific settings
~/.aws/credentials - for credentials shared between SDKs
```

Of course, you can set the environment directly,

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="Your AWS Access Key ID"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="Your AWS Secret Access Key"
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  Unfortunately I still get the same error.  I did a reinstall of boto following the steps on github, clone from github, cd to boto, run python setup.py install.  Even so I don't see a /etc/boto.cfg file with the other two files created manually by me.  I am assuming the .boto file that contains the credentials only resides in the home directory.

Comment: the .boto folder and credentials file are created by yourself.

Comment: thanks.  I have the .boto file with credentials sitting in the home directory but still get the same error.  I will try to get a batch file to run just passing the credentials to aws kinesis to check that they are correct.

Comment: wait for your feedback. One more check is, confirm the access key has permission to use kinesis service.

Comment: just completed configuring a windows machine, ran the same steps and got the same error. Did a bit more investigation and found that the account quoted in the error is my IAM account, so logged into aws with that using a user name and password - not the access key etc - and was able to create a stream.  Will check on how to log in with the access keys and need to find out if I have installed boto correctly.

Comment: Yes, aws login account is different with access key. In service `IAM`, click the user name, go to `Access Credentials` --> `manage access keys`, it will generate the access key for that user. Good luck.

Comment: I have gained a bit more of an unserstanding of the code in the bridge.py and to me it looked like it was never going to create a kinesis stream so I added some lines in myself

Comment: I get feedback that the stream has been created but also includes the following that looks like an error  Starting MQTT-to-Kinesis bridge
Bridge Connected, looping...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bridge.py", line 135, in <module>
bridge.client.loop_forever()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 1212, in loop_forever
...A few more lines like the above then this
self.on_connect(self, self._userdata, flags_dict, result)
TypeError: on_connect() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)

Comment: can you put the detail and error in your question with format.

Comment: The error is in the client.py in the section    self.on_connect(self, self._userdata, flags_dict, result) TypeError: on_connect() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given).  I am not why it thinks there is 5 arguments as the variable called argcount prints out the number 4.  Sorry about the formatting.